# how to rewrite for extending functions?

Tags: c#, string

I'm a bit confused about how to rewrite some separing url code into string extensions.
For instance, I have:

```
    var urlSections = RemovePostfix('/', RemovePrefix("/", requestedPath)).Split('/');
```

using these methods:

```
public static string RemovePostfix(char postfix, string value)
{
    if (value.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (value[value.Length - 1] != postfix)
    {
        return value;
    }

    return value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1);
}

public string RemovePrefix(string prefix, string value)
{
    if (prefix.Length == 0 || !value.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return value;
    }

    return value.Substring(prefix.Length);
}
```

Now, i wanted to move them into separeted class for String Extension:

```
public string RemovePrefix(this string prefix, string value)

public static string RemovePostfix(this char postfix, string value)
```

But, i dont how to call them right to be similar to original invoking:

```
var urlSections = RemovePostfix('/', RemovePrefix("/", requestedPath)).Split('/');
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but:
`requestedPath.RemovePrefix("/").RemovePostfix('/').Split('/')`
?

Comment: you go from : `MyMethod(someString);` to `someString.MyExtensionMethod();`

Comment: @vc74 RemovePostfix first argument need to be char. and i'm confused how to manage this

Comment: @lakykytik in an extension method, the first argument will be the object the method applies on and the second argument will be the first argument to pass to the method. In your case, `RemovePostfix(this string theStringToApplyTheMethodOn, char theFirstArgument)`

Comment: @lakykytik The confusion comes from the back you've inverted the parameters, the first one is the one the method applies to and should be `string value` in your case, not `char postfix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the input string as the `this` parameter, i.e., the string you want to extend with this extension method. Not the prefix or postfix which you want to pass explicitly:

```cs
public static string RemovePrefix(this string value, string prefix)

public static string RemovePostfix(this string value, char postfix)
```

Now you can do a call like

```cs
string[] urlSections = requestedPath.RemovePrefix("/").RemovePostfix('/').Split('/');
```

However, a better option is to use the [Uri Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri), and specifically the [Uri.Segments Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments) for this task.